# Automatic Instagram Posting in Python

Tags: python, instagram

I am looking for the best solution for Python to autopost to instagram from a database of images. I have already made a script using instabot that does this but cant figure out how to post a carousel of images, instead of just one.

I am wondering what the current best solution for Python Instagram coding is as there is quite a lot of outdated information floating around the web...

Comment: Take a look at [this api](https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=post_album#instagram_private_api.Client.post_album)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use A Combination Of Selenium and PyAutoGUI And It Will Be Really Easy! :D

Hope It Helps,

Yash

Comment: I have tried Selenium but emulating a mobile version of www.instagram.com with it doesnt seem to give you all of the options that are available from the actual app...

Comment: @Bimons, There Is A Trick That You Can Put A HTTP Header Into Chrome By Using That